# Rails 3 - Custom JSON with Conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to DRY up my code and I have two methods that do almost the same thing but add an extra fields for one instance.  It is formatting JSON in Rails and trying to see if there is a way where I can perform an if statement within the result.collect similar to below.  Any help is much appreciated

```
results.collect{ |result| { :type => defined?(result.type) ? result.type : "Total", 
    :jan => result.jan, :feb => result.feb, :mar => result.mar, :apr => result.apr, 
    :may => result.may, :jun => result.jun, :jul => result.jul, :aug => result.aug, 
    :sep => result.sep, :oct => result.oct, :nov => result.nov, :dec => result.dec } }
```

in this statement

```
:type => defined?(result.type) ? result.type : "Total"
```

I want to be able perform a check if result.type exists in the query then list it else just put "Total"

Any ideas how to perform this?  Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing in the method to check if with_type or not.  If true then I added the type select statement in and if false then added

```
Select 'Total' as Type
```

I was hoping to figure out how to modify the json as in the question but modifying the composed_scope worked too.